# Finding elements of embedded browser with AutoIT

Tags: autoit

Here is my code:

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
GUICreate( "Main", 1200, 700 )
$viewer = ObjCreate( "Shell.Explorer.2" )
GUICtrlCreateObj( $viewer, 5, 5, 1000, 690 )
$viewer.navigate( "url_for_website" )
GUISetState( @SW_SHOW )
$running = 1
While $running
 $event = GUIGetMsg()
 Switch $event
  Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
     $running = 0
 EndSwitch
WEnd
```

How would I go about finding user input fields with the code above? A push in the right direction would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you out with understanding as this is a great script for IE. Also, it should give you an idea on how to go about implementing what you'd like to do:: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/files/file/227-ieau3/